# Connecting Nexus 9 in adb

Tags: android

I have a problem connecting nexus 9 as a ADB device. Whenever I plug in Nexus 9, Windows 7 automatically detects it and installs it as a portable device. I uninstalled it but every time I plug it again it makes it portable device. I tried to update the driver and show the location of the driver I downloaded, it keeps on saying that it has the latest MTP driver.

I have the Nexus 9 in developer mode, PTP mode and also the debugging is on.
What should I do? How do I connect it for development?
Thanks

Comment: try change to camera mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you turn on USB debugging on device (Settings->Developer Options->USB Debugging)?  If not, machine won't recognize device as ADB.

Comment: I did this, and it did not seem to work, I tried to restart my machine and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the Nexus 9 to be fussy regarding USB cables. I have various cables which work fine with adb and my Nexus 5 but they don't work with my Nexus 9 in MTP or PTP mode.

The only USB cable I can get to work is the one which came with my Nexus 9. 
Its actually a Motorola cable with a hologram sticker on it. Although this may not be what ships standard with the device since I bought it without original packing.

Answer (score 0):

Install MoboRobo or moboginie on your pc if you are using widnows.It'll definitely work.